# Stored output into an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So I need to create a method that takes in an array of names and outputs a set of strings. How do I stored that output into an array? so instead of having an array of names I have an array of greetings?

```html
def badge_maker(array)
  array.each do |i|
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7
      array[counter] << "Hello, my name is #{i}."
      counter += i
    end
    return array
  end
end
arrayOne = ["Edsger","Ada","Charles","Alan","Grace","Linus","Matz"]

badge_maker(arrayOne)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but should do the trick:

```
def badge_maker(names)
  greetings = [] # initialize greetings as an empty array
  names.each do |name| # for each name in the names array
    greetings << "Hello, my name is #{name}." # add a greeting for that name
  end
  return greetings # return the array of all greetings, at the end
end
arrayOne = ["Edsger","Ada","Charles","Alan","Grace","Linus","Matz"]

badge_maker(arrayOne)
```

Or, if you're wanting to actually transform the original array, rather than create a new array of greetings, then do this:

```
def badge_maker(names)
  names.map! do |name| # for each name in the names array
   "Hello, my name is #{name}." # convert it to a greeting for that name
  end
end
arrayOne = ["Edsger","Ada","Charles","Alan","Grace","Linus","Matz"]

badge_maker(arrayOne)
# now, arrayOne will contain an array of greetings, not names
```

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-product), [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join).

```
arr = ["Edsger","Ada","Charles","Alan","Grace","Linus","Matz"]

["How 'ya doin, "].product(arr).map(&:join)
  #=> ["How 'ya doin, Edsger", "How 'ya doin, Ada", "How 'ya doin, Charles",
  #    "How 'ya doin, Alan", "How 'ya doin, Grace", "How 'ya doin, Linus",
  #    "How 'ya doin, Matz"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map!` if you want to modify the original array.  But--however you approach it--an iterative method like `each` or `map` is your friend here because it implicitly handles the number of elements in the collection.

```
def badge_maker(array)
  array.map! do |el|
    "Hello " + el 
  end
end

array_one = ["Edsger","Ada","Charles","Alan","Grace","Linus","Matz"]

badge_maker(array_one)

puts array_one
#=> Hello Edsger
#=> Hello Ada
#=> Hello Charles
#=> Hello Alan
#=> Hello Grace
#=> Hello Linus
#=> Hello Matz
```